# When I run my VBA, it's adding a record to the database but it's blank and doesn't include any of the data in the Excel file

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

When I press the button, it runs but just adds a blank record to the database.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub uploadBtn_Click()
uploadData
End Sub

Sub uploadData()
    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim l_row As Long
    Dim s_surname As String
    Dim s_forename As String
    Dim s_othernames As String
    Dim s_initials As String
    Dim s_DOB As Date
    Dim s_date_started As Date
    Dim s_date_left As Date
    Dim s_job_title As String
    Dim s_can_book_jobs As Boolean
    Dim s_notes As String
    Dim s_job_type As String
    Dim s_paxton_id As Integer


    With ActiveSheet
        conn.Open "DSN=Backup;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=Microsoft Office;DATABASE=<DATABASE>"

        l_row = last_row_with_data(1, ActiveSheet) + 1

        s_surname = .Cells(l_row, 1)
        s_forename = .Cells(l_row, 2)
        s_othernames = .Cells(l_row, 3)
        s_initials = .Cells(l_row, 4)
        s_DOB = .Cells(l_row, 5)
        s_date_started = .Cells(l_row, 6)
        s_date_left = .Cells(l_row, 7)
        s_job_title = .Cells(l_row, 8)
        s_can_book_jobs = .Cells(l_row, 9)
        s_notes = .Cells(l_row, 10)
        s_job_type = .Cells(l_row, 11)
        s_paxton_id = .Cells(l_row, 12)

        conn.Execute "INSERT INTO dbo.Employee_List (Surname, Forename, Other_Names, Initials, DOB, Date_Started, Date_Left, Job_Title, Can_Book_In_Jobs, Notes, Job_Type, PaxtonID) VALUES ('" & s_surname & "', '" & s_forename & "', '" & s_othernames & "', '" & s_initials & "', '" & s_DOB & "', '" & s_date_started & "', '" & s_date_left & "', '" & s_job_title & "', '" & s_can_book_jobs & "', '" & s_notes & "', '" & s_job_type & "', '" & s_paxton_id & "')"
        conn.Close
        Set conn = Nothing
    End With
End Sub

Public Function last_row_with_data(ByVal lng_column_number As Long, shCurrent As Variant) As Long
    last_row_with_data = shCurrent.Cells(Rows.Count, lng_column_number).End(xlUp).Row
End Function
```

Comment: `l_row = last_row_with_data(1, ActiveSheet) + 1` ... doesn't this mean `l_row` refers to a blank row, because of the `+ 1`?

Comment: It does indeed, how do I get it to insert all of the lines instead of just the last one?

Comment: @Jackawan you can either iterate over all lines or use Select (from Excel)/Insert (into DB)  combination

Comment: `For x = 1 to l_row`, then replace .`Cells(l_row, etc.)` with `.Cells(x, etc.)`